# Синтезатор своей речи C#

Tags: c#

Требуется написать самый примитивный синтезатор , который, вместо встроенных в систему голосов, будет использовать мой собственный. Можно использовать голосовые движки, но тогда каким образом написать самую примитивную звуковую библиотеку для него(без учета ударений , интонации и т. д.)?

Comment: Вспомнился предвыборный анекдот про Ельцина: "ладно, Борис Николаевич, вы нам хотя бы алфавит наговорите в микрофон - а мы дальше сами нарежем вам предвыборную речь". Это если на уровне чайника. А вообще, скажем, в любом гласном звуке можно выделить три основные частоты - просто это будет очень сильно синтетический голос, а вы же хотите себя послушать со стороны.

Comment: Для синтеза речи используются "голосовые движки". Они используют звуковые библиотеки (голоса) для произношения.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте для начала поиграть с System.Speech.Synthesis, а после использовать TTS движки-например Digalo и Katerina
Катеньку можете скачать [отсюда](https://sweet211.ru/action/download/downloadid/460/)

```
SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();

synth.Speak("This example demonstrates a basic use of Speech Synthesizer");
```